# Set Cross-Origin Cookies Using POST Method

Tags: javascript, cookies, http-post, fetch, cross-domain

I wish to set cross-origin cookies in server side using POST method.

Cors settings are set up in server side to allow the cross-domain requests and credentials.

After sending a POST from a cross-domain JS application, the cookie is not shown in the browser although the response has set-cookies headers.

However, using GET method to set the cross-domain Cookie from the server works fine and it is saved in the browser.

I failed to find some documentation about this, much appreciated if anyone could explain why the cookies can’t be set using POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookie set by other server will only be visible in the origin site.

For example, you have site.com and ads.com. Site.com wants to use some resources from ads.com.

- Step 1: site.com sends a GET/POST request to ads.com.
- Step 2: ads.com sends a response with cookie(ad_id=blala) attached. This cookie originates from ads.com and will only be visible at ads.com.
- Step 3: site.com sends other requests with the cookie(ad_id=blala) to ads.com.

If you check cookies in site.com, you cannot find the ad_id cookie because this cookie is only visible in ads.com.

In this case, to view the cookie, go to ads.com rather than your site.